# Cosa vuol dire "squadrato" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Ma il mio amore è Paco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Ricordo che si passò una mano davanti agli occhi, forse per cancellare l’apparizione di Paco nella sua tenuta ordinaria per mercati e fiere: in camicia a disegni di fiori e frutta, corpetto grigioferro, **squadrato** e con tanti taschini incolonnati da somigliare a un mobiletto per ufficio, calzoni rosso mattone e scarpe polacchine della medesima tinta.

Ho cercato il termine "squadrare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di questo "squadrato" che si legge nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squadrato significa semplicemente che il corpetto di Paco, la sua tenuta da lavoro, aveva una forma quadrata, aderente al corpo con tanti taschini incolonnati.

In questa immagine ne puoi vedere una versione moderna:

[image]

Comment: Non mi era neanche chiaro cosa volesse dire l'autore con "taschini incolonnati", ma questa fotografia ha chiarito il mio dubbio.

Answer (score 2):

Va probabilmente inteso nel senso di

> **Squadrato**
>
> 2. Spigoloso; marcato, segnato: *un volto duro, s.*
>
> ([Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/squadrato.html))

ossia che non ha le forme tipiche di un indumento, curve morbide dovute al corpo organico che c'è sotto e a un tessuto leggero, bensì appare formato da spigoli netti: come in un quadrato (quindi più simile a un mobile di legno che a una figura umana).